# Why did Shimano name them V Brakes?

Tags: brakes, shimano, history, trivia

Why did Shimano name and trademark their variety of direct pull brakes: V-Brakes®?

[image]

Is it because of shape? The two arms look kind of like a V? That seems a fail as they are more parallel than most cantilever brakes, which are much more V-ish.

Is it because there were earlier series: I, II, III, IV, and finally V brakes?

Historical references please.

Comment: Huh! Is that how you pronounce "Wie" in German -- as 'V'?  So V-Bombs were Wie-Bombs? :-)

Comment: I don't think that link is Weismann link is true -- I believe (but don't have references) that Marinovative and IRD both had V-brakes in production in the US in 1989 / 1990.

Comment: Did they call them "V" or "Wie" brakes? :-)

Comment: @RoboKaren now History and Trivia need wiki tags.

Comment: I'm vaguely recalling that there was another (possibly earlier) design that was referred to as a "U-brake".

Comment: Hm. Yeah, there were U-brakes in the mid 80s on mountain bikes, but they were quickly recognized to be  badly implemented by sticking the brakes on the chainstays. But the braking performance was good when not installed there, so it might be the origin.

Comment: @RoboKaren In German, the letter W is pronounced like an English V, and a German V is pronounced like an English F.

Comment: Seems unlikely that Shimano would call their brakes after someone who could claim to be their inventor.

Answer (score 7):

Apparently they were invented by a guy called [Florian Wiesmann](http://wiesmann-bikes.de/brake_hi.htm) who called his brakes "Wies-brakes", which sounds a lot like "V brakes" to an English speaker.

In 1991 he made this brake:

[image: Wie-Brake I, 1991]

Apart from the centred brake cable attachment, that's very much like a modern V brake. By 1996 he had something you'd look at and swear it was a slightly fancy-looking V brake clone, and that [seems to be the year Shimano](https://www.oldschoolracing.ch/archiv/marinovative/) introduced the V brake.

In 1991 Ben Capron was also selling his [Marinovative V brake](http://mombat.org/MOMBAT/BikeHistoryPages/Marinovative.html) that also looks just like a modern V brake. IRD also began selling their Widget brake. So "who invented the V brake" is a complex question and it may well have been a parallel discovery.

[Mombat](https://mombat.org/) say on a link I got from Google cache because the page doesn't appear to exist now:

> [IRD] Developed the Widget brake, because they needed a brake that could mount to the rear swing arm. This and the Marinovative Brake are the progenitor to today's V-brakes.

Comment: Trivia note: Wiesman is not the same person as Weimann who also made brakes. :-)

Comment: Looks like Marinovative never contemporaneously called them V brakes. Just cheap tricks.

Comment: The marinovatives look a lot more like a modern V-brake than the Wiesman brakes. I suspect the real reason is that V-brake sounds cool, and it was Shimano's marketing department, and its easy to use across the world.

Comment: @Batman except that they were called V brakes in 1991, and Shimano didn't "invent" them until 1996.

Comment: Who was calling them V brakes in 1991? Wies would sound like "Vice" to an english speaker, not "Vee" as V-brakes is pronounced. Marinovative's were called Cheap Trick as Robokaren pointed out.

Comment: http://mombat.org/MOMBAT/BikeHistoryPages/Kestrel.html; Looks like the 1988 Kestrel Nitro had a brake designed by Bontrager (Kestrel/Bontrager ELS) which looks a lot like a V-brake (found via one of his rants: http://www.compint.com/stinkingweasels/BontragerRants/VBrakes.htm)

Comment: @Batman "Wies" is pronounced "Veece" (rhymes with "fleece"); you're confusing it with "Weis".

Comment: In 1990 I made something similar to the brake pictured. Because of the changed mechanical advantage it was very powerful but needed careful adjustment as the brake lever had a short cable pull. I made it because I was experimenting with stems and the split straddle arrangement doesn't need a cable hanger (which was incorporated in that bike's original stem).